# Path o a file in Windows Service

Tags: c#

In my Windows Service Solution I had to add a json file (the same level as the appSetings file) which I had to read and write into.

I know that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will return [Application.exe location] So I use

```
var rawJson = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _GridGeneratorConfig.UpdateTrackerLogFileName));`
```

But when I am testing in Debug mode - I was not able to see the file in /Bin/Debug folder where the compiled .exe is and I was not able to read it.

Only after I added to the .csproj I was able

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="UpdateTrackerLog.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
      </ItemGroup>
```

Also any Update in the content of the file is only applied to the file copied to the executable folder but I am not able to see the changes in the file that is actually in the solution. can you recommend a right approach for getting the path to this file.

Comment: Why should a change at runtime affect your source files? You usually don't want this.

Comment: What is your question here? You have to tell the build system to copy files over (which is done in csproj), so the behaviour is correct

Comment: @Sascha All I am asking is   my  <ItemGroup> project5t configuration mentioned above right? And is there a way the changes to be applied to the file in the solution also?

Comment: Your source code (the solutionm configuration files, graphical assets, etc) are build and copied to the output which is meant to be separate. There is no way back. You could write yourself a tooling or something like this, but it is meant to be one way